# VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” when checking for duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with a Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error".

I have used the exact same code many times before but for some reason I cannot make it function in this sub .

```
Sub Checkduplicates()

    Dim tracker As Workbook

    Set tracker = ActiveWorkbook

    With tracker.Sheets("Tracker")

        Dim sEntity As String, sAmt As Double, sRow As Integer

        sEntity = .Cells(Row, 6).Value
        sAmt = .Cells(Row, 11).Value

        If Row > 1010 Then sRow = Row - 1000 Else sRow = 4

        For sRow = sRow To Row - 1

            If .Cells(sRow, 6).Value = sEntity And .Cells(sRow, 11).Value = sAmt Then

                  Call GetAnswer

            End If
        Next sRow

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: try to add an errorhandler to find the line that gives you an error. It might be helpfull while debugging

Answer (score 0):

`row` in `sEntity = .Cells(row, 6).Value` and `sAmt = .Cells(row, 11).Value` is undeclared and undefined. It looks like it should be the last populated cell in column F.

```
Sub Checkduplicates()

    Dim tracker As Workbook

    Set tracker = ActiveWorkbook

    With tracker.Sheets("Tracker")

        Dim sEntity As String, sAmt As Double, sRow As LONG, rw as LONG

        rw = .cells(.rows.count, "F").end(xlup).row
        sEntity = .Cells(rw, 6).Value
        sAmt = .Cells(rw, 11).Value

        If Row > 1010 Then sRow = Row - 1000 Else sRow = 4

        For sRow = sRow To rw - 1

            If .Cells(sRow, 6).Value = sEntity And .Cells(sRow, 11).Value = sAmt Then

                  Call GetAnswer

            End If
        Next sRow

    End With

End Sub
```

Use Option Explicit.